# how to verify if user already login to ADFS

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

My web app need to authenticate with ADFS for single sign on (SSO). Which mean if user is already login to ADFS, when user access web app, web app need to verify if the user is already login to ADFS. If yes then redirect user to page 1, else page 2. I am using java-saml from (https://github.com/mguessan/java-saml). Is it possible to verify if the user is already login to ADFS?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/mguessan/java-saml, it seems it does not provide a Servlet Filter implementation, like e.g. Spring Security SAML implementation or other toolkit are doing it.
If you always want to do SSO (and do not want to provide a local login),
it might be best to create a filter on your own and directly trigger so called SP-initiated SSO flow to ADFS based SAML IdP. Just have a look at https://github.com/mguessan/java-saml/blob/master/samples/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/src/main/webapp/dologin.jsp